# How to solve problem of updating css of lightning components with every release of Salesforce?

Tags: lightning, css, slds

Lightning make changes in there css with every release. Most of time these changes were minor so we didn't make any changes. But like in summer 18 release there were big changes and we have to release patches for all of our lightning releases(https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_lc_css.htm). Is there a way we can solve this problem. How can we remain in css version of our choice(like in apex). Like I want my css to remain in v42 not upgrade to v43.

Answer (score 2):

We raised a case with salesforce after summer 2018 release since we  were brutally affected by these SLDS class name changes. we had to touch 300 odd components in around 800 places. The main change was classes like `slds-large-size--2-of-12` where changed to `slds-large-size_2-of-12`. `--` was changedto `_` in BEM part of the class

The answer we got was these are not backward compatible and they were mentioned in the release notes that they will change. We asked the same question if staying in v42 will help but sadly the answer is No.

we ended up changing the 300 components since our production application will run into loads of issues post production upgrade this weekend.

**Response from salesforce:**

We heard back from our R&D team and so the change to the class names of the base components is not tied to the api version. The old SLDS "--" styles are still usable in that if you apply them to elements using a style tag, they will still work.

But you won't be able to override them anymore through css as the base component class names have been changed to match the BEM notation (using an _ instead of --) and is unfortunately not tied to the api version.

"We recommend that you create a class instead of targeting a class name you don’t own, since those classes might change anytime. For example, don’t try to target .slds-input or .lightningInput, as they are CSS classes that are available by default in base components."

Comment: we also did something similar. Yes I am looking for some solution for it. Changing and testing css every time is cumbersome job with managed package and multiple customers.

Comment: They do seem to say if you directly use the classes in style tag it would still work, just using them to override css or increase specificity is where it will break. Maybe something you want to look at @ManjotSingh